# How to add a second Glassfish domain in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dns, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish(3.1) from Eclipse(3.6) and it was very easy to get started with.
I now have the need to use two domains in Glassfish from my eclipse. I've manually created a second domain (`asadmin create-domain --portbase someNumber domain2`) and I can login to that domain from the browser.
What I'm unable to do is to add it as a second server in Eclipse.
I try to add a new server but I have no dialog where I can choose the domain.
Another odd issue, which I don't know if it's related, is that in the second dialog I see an error message on the top saying: "error testing remote server: localhos" (that's not a typo, it's leaving out the last letter I also tried it with 127.0.0.1 and the same result occured the 1 was ommitted)
Attached in the end are screenshots of the dialog.
What am I missing? Is it possible that I can only use one glassfish server (no matter how many domains are configured on it)?

Thanks,
Ittai
[image: Define a new server dialog part 1]
[image: Define a new server dialog part 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue either in WTP or the GF plugin.
I guess you typed "localhos": in the server host name field before going to the next step...
The workaround is to exit the registration wizard dialog completely to reset this field to a real localhost (without typing anything there), then, the next screen dialog will let you enter the domain location...

Comment: Thanks! You were wrong about me typing `localhos` as the screenshot shows I typed `localhost` but you were right about the fix itself. Do you know how I can add a remote server? Because this seems to work when I don't touch the `Server's host name` field (which I can only do as long as I work on localhost). When I tried `127.0.0.1` I encountered the same bug and when I tried to configure a different server in our network it was indeed the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of adding the domain name as a program argument in the run configuration of your second server to prevent it from starting the default domain (domain1).